# getContactsByCustomField Performance

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I'm writing a google app script, that sync our crm-contacts to google contacts.

I've a trigger every 10 minutes and only sync 10 contacts per run. But i get many script-timeouts per day.

I found out, that the slowest operation in my script is

```
// Contact already exist?
var existing = ContactsApp.getContactsByCustomField(id, 'crmId');
```

It takes around 20-30 seconds (!!!)

Any Idea why this crucial function is that slow? Or what can I do to find contacts, that already exist in google? Unfortunately, the crmId is the only unique Field to identify the contact.

Comment: Have you tried a more common query, such as [getContactsByEmailAddress()](http://goo.gl/Z5K984) instead? If the contact doesn't exist, this will return a 0-length array... if they do, even if not unique, you should have a short list to check for `crmId` in. Alternatively, you could add your crm contacts to a ContactGroup - if `ContactGroup.getContacts()` is faster than the custom field query, you can move your search into pure Javascript using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the hints.

The `ContactGroup.getContacts()` takes the same time as `ContactsApp.getContactsByCustomField()`.

So now I store all contacts in an array once and in the loop, I search this array myself as mentioned by Mogsdad. This works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

That query is slow, Ive used it before too. Back then I noticed that the full http api for contacts doesnt have that query so it seems that apps script is actually searching manually all contacts until if finds that one.
I actually ended up using apps script for that proyect because gas had that search possibility but it certainly looks like google doesnt index by custom fields.

Comment: It isn't indexed by ANY field - even searching by ID is horribly slow. Every query operation in GAS takes around 45-47 seconds. Seems like someone could rewrite the Contacts API USING GAS itself to read the contacts off a sheet.